# C++ Qt unable to open a file

Tags: c++, qt

I'm attempting to write a text editor. I'm unable to open a file. Why? Here's my code:

```
void MainWindow::readfromfile(){
QFile inputFile(":/text.txt");
inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream in(&inputFile);
QString line = in.readAll();
inputFile.close();
ui->textEdit->setPlainText(line);
QTextCursor cursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 1);

}
```

and

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    connect(ui->actionOpen,SIGNAL(triggered()),ui->textEdit,SLOT(readfromfile()));   
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" - means what? Crash? Empty `line`? Wrong data?

Comment: Shouldn't the slot connection be to `this` instead of `ui->textEdit` if the slot is defined inside MainWindow?

Comment: @MichaelBurr this means when i click , nothing happens.

Comment: @ChrisV tried, the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems that you are using a text file, so it might be worth specifying that when you open the file:

```
inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
```

Then also check the output of the `open()` call:

```
bool ok = inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly || QIODevice::Text);
if (!ok) qWarning() << "Cannot open file";
```

If the file could not be opened, check that the file path is correct.

Comment: when i put this : inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly || QIODevice::Text); , it gives me errors , http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/2172/screenshot20120218001.png

Comment: There should be only 1 | in both open statements.inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);

Comment: Good practice is to include inputFile.errorString() in the error message, as it might gives clues on why the file couldn't be opened.